# What's the best way to remotely access an iPad mini?

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation

This summer I purchased an iPad mini for my Grandmother. I would like to be able to somehow connect to the iPad to do things like update software, apps, and walk her through questions she may have. Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to do this? She does have her own Apple ID.

Answer (score 1):

Without a jailbreak : Not possible.

For the software update, since iOS 7 there done automatically by the system when connected to a wifi network.